# how to understand from where a function call is made?

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree, treesitter

I am using TreeSitter to parse python code.

I need to understand `check_files_in_directory` is invoked from `GPT4Readability.utils`. I already captured all the function calls. I have to do this programatically.

But now I have to find out from which file `check_files_in_directory` is called. I am struggling to understand what would the logic to do it. Can anyone please suggest?

I have to implement this with a Tree sitter AST parser from scratch. I would appreciate links to proper resources, high-level logic. I am not looking for actual code implementation and instead high-level reasoning.

```
import os
from getpass import getpass
from GPT4Readability.utils import *
import importlib.resources as pkg_resources  


def generate_readme(root_dir, output_name, model):
    """Generates a README.md file based on the python files in the provided directory

    Args:
        root_dir (str): The root directory of the python package to parse and generate a readme for
    """

    # prompt_folder_name = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "prompts")
    # prompt_path = os.path.join(prompt_folder_name, "readme_prompt.txt")

    with pkg_resources.open_text('GPT4Readability.prompts','readme_prompt.txt') as f:         
        inb_msg = f.read()

    # with open(prompt_path) as f:
    #     lines = f.readlines()
    # inb_msg = "".join(lines)

    file_check_result = check_files_in_directory(root_dir)
```

Comment: If you're using VS Code, the "Find All References" command might point you in the right direction

Comment: So, are you creating a cross-reference?  You can use `grep` to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Treesitter parses an individual file, not a code-tree or "project". Also, it does not attempt to identify call graphs (who calls who and where).

What I think you're looking for is a *language-server*, which *does* work at the scope of an entire project and does work out who calls who. These would be the *definitions* and *references* functionality of a language server (commonly called an LSP, although that's not strictly correct). `pyright` is one to look at for Python.

If you were satisifed with references within a single source file, i.e. the function is both defined and called in the same module, then you could write a script to do that by identifying `call` nodes and `function_definition` nodes and matching them up by name.

Such a solution would be imperfect because you can assign a function to a variable of a different name, and those wouldn't match:

```py
def fn():
    return 42

fn_alias = fn

print(fn_alias())
# 42
```

These are the sort of shortcomings that a language-server overcomes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to find, load, and parse (with Treesitter) all of the files that could potentially call `check_files_in_directory()`, then you can query the tree of each of those files to find a `call` node having the identifier "change_files_in_directory". In pseudo-code this might look something like this:

```py
select = tree_sitter_languages.get_language("python").query

for file in possible_files:
    syntax_tree = parse(file)  # --> Treesitter tree
    call_fn_name_nodes = select("(call function: (identifier) @capture)")
    for fn_name in call_fn_name_nodes:
        if fn_name == "check_files_in_directory":
            print(f"found in file {file}")
            break
```

There are a few possible problems, depending on your situation:

**Does not fully qualify called name.** If you have multiple `check_files_in_directory()` functions in the scope of checked files, this will find *all* of them. There's no way yet to tell this is exactly `GPT4Readability.utils.check_files_in_directory()`. That would require some additional code to qualify the name based on imports and so forth.

Also, if the call was in the form `utils.check_files_in_directory()` or `GPT4Readability.utils.check_files_in_directory()` you would need to elaborate the query to check for multiple identifiers.

But maybe that's enough to give you a general strategy you can refine incrementally.